# How to add text over image in table html while image still has hover opacity

Tags: html, css, overlay

I've been searching for the last day or so trying to figure out a way to do this, because whenever I end up doing it, my image is either not centred on my page, it pushes all the other images out of the way, or even if I manage to align it, the image no longer sets it opacity to 0.5 because of the text div in front of it which doesn't affect the image.
[image: Image of site layout with specified box highlighted]
This is the image I am trying to add text in front of, which when clicked on will take the user to another page. That part is all fine, but I can't seem to get the text to appear over it dead centre.

This is my code.

[image: Image of code without text for image]

and my class style
[image: Image of style]

I added the position in order to be able to use z-index to make my text appear on top, but that stops the image from going transparent.

This is what it looks like with the text attached.

[image: Image of site with text inside image off centre]

My html is the same as before, only with a div underneath my image so it looks like

```
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <img src="Images/emielostrich.png" class="boxImage"/>   
          <div class="overlayText">Test</div>          
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
```

[image: Image of Css Style]

Any help is appreciated as well as any general comments as I'm only just really starting html.

Comment: Would you consider embedding the image as css background?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) And please don't send us to external repos or stuff like that either - the [mre] to reproduce your issue belongs directly into your question.

Comment: Consider using flex for positioning the text, background-image for showing the image but making sure they all look the same size and possibly move away from table to flex or grid as your data is not really tabular in nature.

Comment: Spotted a serious error in your code. The part about `emielostrich.png`. I think it's an Emu :) Anyway... See if this helps :) https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp

Comment: @CuteyfromCuteCode I ended up going with this, thanks a lot for the help and suggestions all!

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

```css
/* img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(110%) blur(1px); Chrome, Safari, Opera
/*     filter: grayscale(100%); */
.test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('http://img.khelnama.com/sites/default/files/mediaimages/gallery/2012/Aug/RTR36KBH.jpg');
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
.test p {
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;     

}
.test2 {
  background-image: url('https://hjdp0w.bn1301.livefilestore.com/y2pv5djwOeNCtiz5obh1cxcBBwW0tSrBueBDPdHZQaORQMEfeW9u_sJa-2BJCqSg1a0CClVGyUBNFmafC_d8MzkSWX1fdR7RDU5vl3NM19l0fs/wood.jpg?psid=1');
  line-height: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
.test3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.6)), url('https://36.media.tumblr.com/742ec9bb05056b2821ff8f0eb7768348/tumblr_o325ltMBRD1tomxvuo8_1280.jpg');
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 500px;
}
.test2 p {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  padding: 10px;
}
.test3 p {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>Image with Dark Overlay</p>
</div>
<div class="test2">
  <p>Text with some translucent background thing</p>
</div>
<div class="test3">
  <p>Floor Fade Test</p>
</div>
```